# Beignet does not find CPU

Tags: opencl, intel, beignet

I am using Beignet to try out OpenCL on my notebook with a 4th gen i7 and integrated graphic accelerator, running Ubuntu 16.04

Upon running clinfo I only find 1 platform and 1 device, which is the graphic accelerator.
Should I not find also the CPU itself? As I have read that OpenCL allows to use the host as a normal device and run some kernels on it

Comment: You should! Which CPU are you using? OpenCL support? and your OpenCL version? Normally, all the Intel CPU I have used so far give full support for any version of OpenCl

Comment: Must be a driver issue. Even in windows, my hd400 had 8 execution units but after an update, it was 12 execution units.

Comment: Thank you for you help

I am currently using a Intel Core i7-4510U with an integrated Intel HD 4400.

Answer (score 1):

Beignet does not include an ICD for Intel CPUs, it's only for the integrated GPU:

```
Beignet is an open source implementation of the OpenCL specification - a generic compute oriented API. This code base contains the code to run OpenCL programs on Intel GPUs which basically defines and implements the OpenCL host functions required to initialize the device, create the command queues, the kernels and the programs and run them on the GPU.
```

(from the official beignet webpage)

You need to install the intel ICD, since there appears to not be an open source OCL implementation for intel CPUs.